# Jenkinsfile print parameters nicely

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, hcl

We have a Jenkinsfile with parameters declared as follows:

```
def params = [string(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', value: environment),
              string(name: 'VERSION',     value: version),
              string(name: 'REGION',      value: region)]
```

I'd like to echo these, for example

```
DEPLOYING: ENVIRONMENT=STAGING, VERSION=1.3.0, REGION=EU
```

However calling `echo "$params"` prints:

```
[@string(name=ENVIRONMENT,value=STAGING), @string(name=VERSION,value=1.3.0), @string(name=REGION,value=EU)]
```

I tried iterating the array - e.g. :

`params.each { echo it }` throws `UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class java.lang.String is using symbol ‘string’`

`params.each { echo it.name }`  throws `RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.UninstantiatedDescribable name`

How can I print the `params` array nicely?

EDIT - from Matt Schuchard's response:

```
def params = [string(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', value: "STAGING"),
              string(name: 'VERSION',     value: "1.3.0"),
              string(name: 'REGION',      value: "EU")]
print "$params"

params.each() { param, value ->
    print "Parameter: ${param}, Value: ${value}"
}
```

returns (i.e. Value is all null):

```
[@string(name=ENVIRONMENT,value=STAGING), @string(name=VERSION,value=1.3.0), @string(name=REGION,value=EU)]
Parameter: @string(name=ENVIRONMENT,value=STAGING), Value: null
Parameter: @string(name=VERSION,value=1.3.0), Value: null
Parameter: @string(name=REGION,value=EU), Value: null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Groovy map iterator lambda method (such as `each`) to iterate over the `params` map. An example follows:

```
params.each() { param, value ->
  print "Parameter: ${param}, Value: ${value}"
}
```

If you decide to use this directly inside a `pipeline` block, then this will need to be placed inside a `script` block when using declarative DSL.

Comment: I have edited the question to include this code - Value is 'null' in all cases

Comment: @user1016765 So it sounds like the `params` object does not have a `map` operator method defined in its class even though it is basically a `map` type when accessed. That is a bug I was honestly not expecting. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries - the code extracting the values from the @string(...) works so all good.

Answer (score 0):

There ***must*** be a better way but the following works

Iterating the params array:

```
 1. Cast each parameter to a regular String
 2. Extracted the value between @string( VALUE )
 3. Split the key/value pairs first by comma ','
 4. Then split each side of the above by equals '='
 5. Concatenate the second argument
```

> ```
> def pretty(params) {
>     def s = ""
>     params.each { param ->
>         def a = ("${param}" =~ /^@string\((.+)\)$/)[ 0 ][ 1 ]
>         def b = a.split(",")
>         s = s + b[0].split("=")[1] + "=" + b[1].split("=")[1] + "\n"
>     }
>     return s
> }
> ```

Returns:

```
ENVIRONMENT=STAGING
VERSION=1.3.0
REGION=EU
```

Answer (score 0):

is `params` goal is to parameterized the build?
if this is the case, you can use [`parameters`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters:%7E:text=%7D-,parameters) directive

> The `parameters` directive provides a list of parameters that a user
> should provide when triggering the Pipeline.
> The values for these
> user-specified parameters are made available to Pipeline steps via the
> `params` object.

declerative pipeline:

> Declarative Pipeline supports parameters out-of-the-box, allowing the
> Pipeline to accept user-specified parameters at runtime via the
> parameters directive.

```
parameters {
        string(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', defaultValue: 'STAGING', description: 'Environment to test. e.g: production/develop'),
        string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: '1.3.0', description: 'Version to run'),
        string(name: 'REGION', defaultValue: 'EU', description: 'Region')
    }
```

scripted pipeline:

> Configuring parameters with Scripted Pipeline is
> done with the properties step, which can be found in the Snippet
> Generator

```
properties([
    parameters([
        string(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', defaultValue: 'STAGING', description: 'Environment to test. e.g: production/develop'),
        string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: '1.3.0', description: 'Version to run'),
        string(name: 'REGION', defaultValue: 'EU', description: 'Region')
    ])
])
```

now, those parameters are accessible as members of the `params` variable
so, then you can simply use:

```
params.each() { param, value ->
    print "Parameter: ${param}, Value: ${value}"
}
```